# kotlin retrofit как дождаться ответа

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Только учусь и видимо не до конца понял как работать с retrofit.
Есть recyclerView подписанный на изменение.
С начала сделал viewModel и объект с данными и все работало.
Затем поменял, чтобы данные получались с сервера и вот тут возникла проблема, вот как делаю

```
object PeopleData {
private val mService: RetrofitServices = Common.retrofitService
fun getPeoples(page: String): MutableList<PeopleEntity> {
    var listPeopleEntity: MutableList<PeopleEntity> = ArrayList()

    mService.getAllPeople(page).enqueue(object : Callback<ListPeopleEntity> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ListPeopleEntity>,
            response: Response<ListPeopleEntity>
        ) {

            Log.d("PeopleData", "onResponse")
            listPeopleEntity = response.body()?.results as MutableList<PeopleEntity>
            Log.d("PeopleData", listPeopleEntity.size.toString())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ListPeopleEntity>, t: Throwable) {

            Log.d("PeopleData", "onFailure")
        }

    })
    Log.d("PeopleData2", listPeopleEntity.size.toString())
    return listPeopleEntity
}
```

Если смотреть логи, то там следующие

D/PeopleData2: 0

D/PeopleData: onResponse

D/PeopleData: 10

Как я понимаю, он не ждет ответа от сервера и передает обратно во viewModel пустой список и соответсвено тот ничего не отображает. Пробовал сюда приделать корутины, но в них еще не разбираюсь и ничего из этого не вышло, результат тот же самый

и вот сам вызов

```
class PeopleViewModel: ViewModel() {
var peopleList: MutableLiveData<List<PeopleEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
var nextPage: String = "1"

init {
    PeopleData.getPeoples(nextPage)
}

fun getListPeople() = peopleList
```

}

Помогите пожалуйста, а то бьюсь уже не первый день

Comment: Все верно понимаете. В момент `return listPeopleEntity` запрос на сервер только инициируется, данных еще нет. В этом и суть асинхронного программирования, когда данные придут, будет вызван колбэк `onResponse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы правы, запрос выполняется асинхронно (почитайте про асинхронность). Так как у вас `peopleList` является `MutableLiveData`, в него можно "запостить" (присвоить) новое значение. Присвойте новый список, когда придёт ответ от сервера.

```
fun getPeoples(page: String, peopleList: MutableLiveData<List<PeopleEntity>>) {
    mService.getAllPeople(page).enqueue(object : Callback<ListPeopleEntity> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ListPeopleEntity>,
            response: Response<ListPeopleEntity>
        ) {

            Log.d("PeopleData", "onResponse")
            val listPeopleEntity = response.body()?.results as MutableList<PeopleEntity>
            Log.d("PeopleData", listPeopleEntity.size.toString())
            peopleList.postValue(listPeopleEntity)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ListPeopleEntity>, t: Throwable) {

            Log.d("PeopleData", "onFailure")
        }
    })
}
```

Вызов:

```
var peopleList: MutableLiveData<List<PeopleEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
var nextPage: String = "1"

init {
    PeopleData.getPeoples(nextPage, peopleList)
}

fun getListPeople() = peopleList
```

Comment: Кастить `response.body()?.results` уже не нужно :)